# ARM template for enabling Update Management on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, templates, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Could someone help me to enable update management on Azure VM with Azure Resource Manager Template.

I could find any template online to enable it.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management

Answer (score 0):

you cannot enable vm for update management, you can link oms and azure automation with update management enabled. more or less. here's a more or less working variant:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "parameters": {
        "prefix": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "namespace": "[concat(parameters('prefix'), '-la')]",
        "automation": "[concat(parameters('prefix'), '-aa')]",
        "solutions": [
            "AlertManagement",
            "Updates",
            "Security"
        ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
            "name": "[variables('namespace')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-15-preview",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "name": "Standalone"
                }
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "name": "Automation",
                    "type": "linkedServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[variables('automation')]",
                        "[variables('namespace')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', variables('automation'))]"
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
            "name": "[variables('automation')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "name": "OMS"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
            "name": "[concat(variables('solutions')[copyIndex()],'(', variables('namespace'), ')')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "solutions",
                "count": "[length(variables('solutions'))]"
            },
            "plan": {
                "name": "[concat(variables('solutions')[copyIndex()], '(', variables('namespace'), ')')]",
                "promotionCode": "",
                "product": "[concat('OMSGallery/', variables('solutions')[copyIndex()])]",
                "publisher": "Microsoft"
            },
            "properties": {
                "workspaceResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', variables('namespace'))]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[variables('namespace')]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this script work for an already existing Automation Account and Log Analytics Account

Comment: if you adapt it - yes

Comment: Hi guys, I have one question, I am preparing similar ARM template. I need ARM for onboarding VMs into Update Management. My ARM installs MMA or OMS agent or a VM, connect VM to a workspace, but after ARM deployment VM is still not onboarded, there in no Hybrid Worker installed (VMs registry and Automation Account settings), is there any method to fully onboard VM using ARM template?

Comment: there should be, raise a new question, someone might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

I have just included the following script to my VM deployment script. Is it okay

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions",
        "name": "[concat(variables('solutions')[copyIndex()],'(', parameters('workspaceName'), ')')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "copy": {
            "name": "solutions",
            "count": "[length(variables('solutions'))]"
        },
        "plan": {
            "name": "[concat(variables('solutions')[copyIndex()], '(', parameters('workspaceName'), ')')]",
            "promotionCode": "",
            "product": "[concat('OMSGallery/', variables('solutions')[copyIndex()])]",
            "publisher": "Microsoft"
        },
        "properties": {
            "workspaceResourceId": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('workspaceRGName'), 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName')), '2015-03-20').customerId]"
        }
    }
```

Comment: The above script is not referring Automation Account anywhere. How does the Update management enable if i run the script .

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @4c74356b41, any help would be appreciated