# associate an existing Virtual Machine to Update Management Through ARM Template

Tags: arm, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am looking for a ARM Template to add an existing VM to a update management enabled on Automation account.

How can i associate a VM to the update management?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARM template for enabling Update Management on Azure Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018397/arm-template-for-enabling-update-management-on-azure-virtual-machine)

Comment: Based on this blog, you can onboard your vms through an VM extension via an ARM template https://www.danielstechblog.io/deploy-update-management-solution-azure-resource-manager-template/